# How to use collision detection with arrays?

Tags: javascript, class, collision-detection

I'm trying to make a game, but I can't find out how to use collision detection with arrays. I tried this, but it only works for the first object of the array, not for the rest of them:

```
        for (i = 0; i < monsterArray.length; i++) { //Voor else monster in monsterArray
            var monsterX = parseInt(monsterArray[i].style.left);
            var monsterY = parseInt(monsterArray[i].style.top);
            var monsterSize = monsterArray[i].style.width;
            if (spelerX + spelerSize >= monsterX && spelerX <= monsterX + monsterSize && spelerY + spelerSize >= monsterY && spelerY <= monsterY + monsterSize) {
              //location.reload();
              test.innerHTML = "hit"
            } if (!(spelerX + spelerSize >= monsterX && spelerX <= monsterX + monsterSize && spelerY + spelerSize >= monsterY && spelerY <= monsterY + monsterSize)) {
            test.innerHTML = "clear"
            }
        }
```

Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

I've put the whole code below, but it's like 300 lines, sooo.. Yeah...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form Fight: Cube vs Disks</title>
<link href="../Style/style.PoPeriode2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="icon" href="../Afbeeldingen/Enemy%20Sprite.png" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Variable aanmaken
    var bulletPauze = false; //Een onderbreking tussen het afschieten van de bullets
    var bulletRatio = 4; //De verhouding tussen de grootte van de speler en de grootte van de bullet
    var bulletFireRate = 300; //Hoevaak je een kogel kan afschieten

    var containerWidth = 1280; //De breedte van de container
    var containerHeight = 720; //De hoogte van de container

    var keyState = []; //Een array waarin de staat (true of false) van de ingedrukte toetsen wordt opgeslagen
    var down = false;
    var left = false;
    var right = false;
    var up = false;

    var monsterArray = []; //Een array met alle monsters

    var spelerSize = 50; //De grootte van de speler
    var spelerSpeed = 2; //Hoeveel pixels de speler elk 'frame' beweegt
    var spelerX = containerWidth / 2 - (spelerSize / 2); //De X-coordinaat van de speler
    var spelerY = containerHeight / 2 - (spelerSize / 2); //De Y-coordinaat van de speler

    //EventListeners
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { //Bij keydown
        keyState[e.keyCode] = true; //In de array keyState wordt de waarde van de keycode van het event 'true'
    }, true); //Event capturing

    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) { //Bij keyup
        keyState[e.keyCode] = false; //In de array keyState wordt de keycode van het event 'false'
}, true); //Event capturing


    function gameLoop() { //De voortduring van het spel
        //Container collision
        if (spelerX <= 0) { //Check of de speler rechts buiter de container gaat
            spelerX = 1; //Verander de positie van de speler zodat hij weer binnen de container zit
        }
        if (spelerX >= (containerWidth - spelerSize)) { //Check of de speler links buiter de container gaat
            spelerX = containerWidth - spelerSize; //Verander de positie van de speler zodat hij weer binnen de container zit
        }
        if (spelerY <= 0) {  //Check of de speler boven buiter de container gaat
            spelerY = 1; //Verander de positie van de speler zodat hij weer binnen de container zit
        }
        if (spelerY >= (containerHeight - spelerSize)) { //Check of de speler onder buiter de container gaat
            spelerY = containerHeight - spelerSize; //Verander de positie van de speler zodat hij weer binnen de container zit
        }
        //Controls
        if (keyState[37] || keyState[65]) { //Als a of left arrow is ingedrukt
            //Maak de waarde van left 'true' en de rest 'false'
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = true;
            right = false;

            spelerX -= spelerSpeed; //Beweeg de speler naar links
        }

        if (keyState[39] || keyState[68]) { //Als d of right arrow is ingedrukt
            //Maak de waarde van right 'true' en de rest 'false'
            up = false;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = true;

            spelerX += spelerSpeed; //Beweeg de speler naar rechts
        }
        if (keyState[38] || keyState[87]) { //Als w of up arrow is ingedrukt
            //Maak de waarde van up 'true' en de rest 'false'
            up = true;
            down = false;
            left = false;
            right = false;

            spelerY -= spelerSpeed; //Beweeg de speler naar boven
        }
        if (keyState[40] || keyState[83]) { //Als s of down arrow is ingedrukt
            //Maak de waarde van down 'true' en de rest 'false'
            up = false;
            down = true;
            left = false;
            right = false;

            spelerY += spelerSpeed; //Beweeg de speler naar beneden
        }
        if (keyState[32] && bulletPauze == false) { //Als spatie is ingedrukt en bulletPauze over is
            //Schiet in de richting die 'true' is
            if (right == true) {
                shootR()
            } else if (left == true) {
                shootL()
            } else if (up == true) {
                shootU()
            } else if (down == true) {
                shootD()
            }

            //Hier wordt een pauze tussen het schieten van de bullets gemaakt, zodat je niet steeds achter elkaar kan blijven schieten
            bulletPauze = true; //De pauze begint
            setTimeout(function() { bulletPauze = false; }, bulletFireRate); //Na de waarde van bulletFireRate in ms is de pauze over
        }

        speler.style.left = spelerX + "px"; //Verander elke keer dat het spel geupdated wordt het X coordinaat van de speler naar de waarde van het variable spelerX
        speler.style.top = spelerY + "px"; //Verander elke keer dat het spel geupdated wordt het Y coordinaat van de speler naar de waarde van het variable spelerY

        //Monster Collision
        for (i = 0; i < monsterArray.length; i++) { //Voor else monster in monsterArray
            var monsterX = parseInt(monster.style.left);
            var monsterY = parseInt(monster.style.top);
            var monsterSize = monster.style.width;
            if (spelerX + spelerSize >= monsterX && spelerX <= monsterX + monsterSize && spelerY + spelerSize >= monsterY && spelerY <= monsterY + monsterSize) {
              //location.reload(); //Herlaad de pagina
              test.innerHTML = "hit"
            } if (!(spelerX + spelerSize >= monsterX && spelerX <= monsterX + monsterSize && spelerY + spelerSize >= monsterY && spelerY <= monsterY + monsterSize)) {
            test.innerHTML = "clear"
            }
        }

        setTimeout(gameLoop, 10); //Update de game elke 10 ms

    }

    function monstersAanmaken() { //div's aanmaken die als monster fungeren
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //Bepaal hoeveel monster worden aangemaakt
            monster = document.createElement("div");
            monster.className = "monster"; //Elk aparte div een Class geven
            container.appendChild(monster); //Elk aparte div onder de div 'container' zetten

            monster.style.left = Math.random() * 500 + 'px'; //Willekeurige positie voor het monster gegeven op de X-as
            monster.style.top = Math.random() * 500 + 'px'; //Willekeurige positie voor het monster gegeven op de Y-as
            monsterX = monster.style.left; //Verander de waarde van monsterX naar de 'left' waarde van het HTML element monster
            monsterY = monster.style.top; //Verander de waarde van monsterY naar de 'top' waarde van het HTML element monster
            monsterArray.push(monster) //Elk monster apart toevoegen aan het array

        }
        var monstersAnimerenInterval = setInterval(monstersAnimeren, 200) //Beweeg elke 200 ms de monsters
    }

    function monstersAnimeren() { //Animatie van de monsters
        $(".monster").stop();
        $(".monster").animate( {
            left: speler.style.left, //X-coördinaten van de monsters gelijk maken aan die van de speler
            top: speler.style.top //Y-coördinaten van de monsters gelijk maken aan die van de speler
        }, 8000, 'linear');
        return monster.style.left, monster.style.top;
    }

    function shoot(bullet) {
        container.appendChild(bullet); //Voeg de bullet toe onder de container in de DOM
        bullet.style.width = spelerSize / bulletRatio + "px"; //De grote van de bullet is do grootte van de speler gedeeld door de bulletRatio (Mochten we de grootte later nog veranderen, zodat alles in verhouding blijft)
        bullet.style.height = spelerSize / bulletRatio + "px";
        bullet.style.background = "lightgrey"; //Verander de achtergrondkleur van de bullet naar lichtgrijs
        bullet.style.position = "absolute"; //Verander de positie van de bullet naar absoluut
        bullet.style.top = parseInt(speler.style.top) + spelerSize / 2 - (spelerSize / bulletRatio / 2) + "px"; //De coordinaten van het midden van de bullet zijn het midden van de speler
        bullet.style.left = parseInt(speler.style.left) + spelerSize / 2 - (spelerSize / bulletRatio / 2) + "px";
    }

    function shootD() {
        var bullet = document.createElement("div");
        shoot(bullet); //Voer de functie 'shoot' uit met 'bullet' als argument
        var bulletX = parseInt(bullet.style.left); //De waarde van bulletX wordt de 'left' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var bulletY = parseInt(bullet.style.top); //De waarde van bulletY wordt de 'top' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var animeBullet = setInterval(frame, 1); //Voer elke ms de functie 'frame' uit

        function frame() {
            if (bulletY >= containerHeight - spelerSize / bulletRatio) { //Check of de bullet zich onder buiten de container bevindt
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
            } /*else if (bulletX >= monsterX ) { //Check of de coordinaten van bullet overlappen met de coordinaten van het monster
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
            }*/ else { //Als de bullet niet buiten de container is, en ook geen monster raakt
                bulletY += 2; //Schuif de positie van de bullet steeds met 2 pixels naar onder
                bullet.style.top = bulletY + "px"; //De 'top' waarde van het HTML element 'bullet' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van bulletY
            }
        }
    }

    function shootL() {
        var bullet = document.createElement("div"); //Maak een div aan die in het javascript bestand 'bullet' heet
        shoot(bullet); //Voer de functie 'shoot' uit met 'bullet' als argument
        var bulletX = parseInt(bullet.style.left); //De waarde van bulletX wordt de 'left' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var bulletY = parseInt(bullet.style.top); //De waarde van bulletY wordt de 'top' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var animeBullet = setInterval(frame, 1); //Voer elke ms de functie 'frame' uit

        function frame() {
            if (bulletX <= 0) { //Check of de bullet zich links buiten de container bevindt
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
            } else if (bulletX >= monsterX && bulletX <= (monsterX + monsterSize) && bulletY >= monsterY && bulletY <= (monsterY + monsterSize)) { //Check of de coordinaten van bullet overlappen met de coordinaten van het monster
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
                container.removeChild(bullet);
            } else { //Als de bullet niet buiten de container is, en ook geen monster raakt
                bulletX -= 2; //Schuif de positie van de bullet steeds met 2 pixels naar links
                bullet.style.left = bulletX + "px"; //De 'left' waarde van het HTML element 'bullet' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van bulletX
            }
        }
    }

    function shootR() {
        var bullet = document.createElement("div"); //Maak een div aan die in het javascript bestand 'bullet' heet
        shoot(bullet); //Voer de functie 'shoot' uit met 'bullet' als argument
        var bulletX = parseInt(bullet.style.left); //De waarde van bulletX wordt de 'left' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var bulletY = parseInt(bullet.style.top); //De waarde van bulletY wordt de 'top' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var animeBullet = setInterval(frame, 1); //Voer elke ms de functie 'frame' uit

        function frame() {
            if (bulletX >= containerWidth - spelerSize / bulletRatio) { //Check of de bullet zich rechts buiten de container bevindt
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
            } else if (bulletX >= monsterX[i] && bulletX <= (monsterX[i] + monsterSize) && bulletY >= monsterY[i] && bulletY <= (monsterY[i] + monsterSize)) { //Check of de coordinaten van bullet overlappen met de coordinaten van het monster
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
                monsterShot()
            } else { //Als de bullet niet buiten de container is, en ook geen monster raakt
                bulletX += 2; //Schuif de positie van de bullet steeds met 2 pixels naar rechts
                bullet.style.left = bulletX + "px"; //De 'left' waarde van het HTML element 'bullet' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van bulletX
            }
        }
    }

    function shootU() { //Maak een div aan die in het javascript bestand 'bullet' heet
        var bullet = document.createElement("div");
        shoot(bullet); //Voer de functie 'shoot' uit met 'bullet' als argument
        var bulletX = parseInt(bullet.style.left); //De waarde van bulletX wordt de 'left' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var bulletY = parseInt(bullet.style.top); //De waarde van bulletY wordt de 'top' van het het HTML element 'bullet' in de vorm van een integer
        var animeBullet = setInterval(frame, 1); //Voer elke ms de functie 'frame' uit

        function frame() { //Maak een div aan die in het javascript bestand 'bullet' heet
            if (bulletY <= 0) { //Check of de bullet zich boven buiten de container bevindt
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                container.removeChild(bullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
            } else if (bulletX >= monsterX && bulletX <= (monsterX + monsterSize) && bulletY >= monsterY && bulletY <= (monsterY + monsterSize)) { //Check of de coordinaten van bullet overlappen met de coordinaten van het monster
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Stop de animatie van de bullet
                clearInterval(animeBullet); //Verwijder de bullet uit de DOM
                container.removeChild(bullet);
            } else { //Als de bullet niet buiten de container is, en ook geen monster raakt
                bulletY -= 2; //Schuif de positie van de bullet steeds met 2 pixels naar boven
                bullet.style.top = bulletY + "px"; //De 'top' waarde van het HTML element 'bullet' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van bulletY
            }
        }
    }

    function zzLoadEvents() {
        monstersAanmaken(); //Voer de functie 'monstersAanmaken' uit
        var container = document.getElementById("container"); //Geef het     HTML element 'container' ook de naam 'container' in het Javascript bestand
        var speler = document.getElementById("speler"); //Geef het HTML element 'speler' ook de naam 'speler' in het Javascript bestand
        var test = document.getElementById("test") //Geef het HTML element 'test' ook de naam 'test' in het Javascript bestand

        container.style.width = containerWidth + "px"; //De width van het HTML element 'container' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van containerWidth
        container.style.height = containerHeight + "px"; //De height van het HTML element 'container' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van containerHeight
        monsterSize = monster.style.width + "px"; //De waarde van monsterSize wordt de width van het HTML element monster
        speler.style.width = spelerSize + "px"; //De 'width' waarde van het HTML element 'speler' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van spelerSize
        speler.style.height = spelerSize + "px"; //De 'height' waarde van het HTML element 'speler' wordt het aantal pixels van de waarde van spelerSize


        gameLoop(); //Vanaf nu begint het spel echt
    }

    window.onload = zzLoadEvents; //Voer bij het laden van de pagina de functie 'zzLoadEvents' uit (zz zodat de functies op alfabetische volgorde blijven staan)
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test">text</p>
<div id="container">
    <div id="speler">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the fourth line should that be monsterArray[1] or monsterArray[i] ?

Comment: Oh, that's a type, that should be i too. Doesn't work with that edited nonetheless.

Comment: I think it'd take a good bit of time to scan the code for whatever is going wrong. I'm guessing you've tried console.logging in various places to pinpoint the problem. Just keep putting console.log statements, moving through the flow of the code, until you can see where the problem started. I looked through it for a bit and without the whole app working with your css and images, it is really hard to figure out what might have gone wrong. Also you didn't really say what went wrong so I'm not too sure what the problem was without being able to see it